# How to extract best estimator of a SequentialFeatureSelector

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, sequentialfeatureselector

I have trained a `SequentialFeatureSelector` from sklearn and am now interested in the best model (based on the given scoring method) it produced. Is there a possible way of extracting the parameters and using them generate the model that was used?

I have seen that there exists a `get_params()` function for the `SequentialFeatureSelector`, but I don't undestand how to interpret the output and retrieve the best estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main result of this model is which features it decided to select. You can access that information in various ways. Suppose you have fitted a `selector=SequentialFeatureSelector(...).fit(...)`.

`selector.support_` is a boolean vector, where `True` means it selected that feature. If you started off with 5 features, and told it to select 2, then the vector will be `[True, False, False, False, True]` if it selected the first and last feature.

You can get the same output as above using `selector.get_support()`. If you want the indices rather than a boolean vector, you can use `selector.get_support(indices=True)` - it'll return `[0, 4]` in this case indicating feature number 0 and feature number 3.

To get the feature names (only applies if you fed the model a dataframe):

`selector.feature_names_in_[selector.support_]`

After fitting the selector, if you want it to strip out the unselected features, you can use `selector.transform(X_test)`. The `.transform(X_test)` will apply the *already-fitted* selector to the supplied data. In this example, if `X_test` is 100 x 5, then it'll return a 100 x 2 version where it has only kept the features determined from the initial `.fit()`.

`SequentialFeatureSelector` doesn't keep any of the models fitted during cross-validation. So I think you'd need to fit a new model using the selected features:

```
#Fit selector
selector = SequentialFeatureSelector(
    LogisticRegression(), n_features_to_select=2
).fit(X, y)

print('Selected feature numbers are', selector.get_support(indices=True))

#Use fitted selector to reduce X
X_reduced = selector.transform(X)

#Fit logreg model on the selected features
logreg_fitted = LogisticRegression().fit(X_reduced, y)
```

Alternatively, this ensures consistency with the original estimator by saving you from needing to manually specify all the original parameters:

```
from sklearn.base import clone

best_model = clone(selector.estimator)(**selector.estimator.get_params()).fit(selector.transform(X), y).
```

If you want identical models (down to the random seed) it'll also be necessary to set up the CV appropriately.

Comment: Thats not what I asked (though i appreciate the effort :D). Let me try to phrase it differently... The SequentialFeatureSelector should (from what I understand) train a model for each added feature in each step and at the end of each step compare the accurarcy of these models. It then selects the feature that was added to the model with the highest accuracy. Therefore for the last iteration of the feature selection, the models should be quite good and i would like to extract them.

Comment: At the final iteration, it has one more feature to select. It will go through each remaining feature, adding it into the current model. Then it'll pick one that resulted in the best score. Do you mean that you want all the models from that trial? So if there are 3 unselected features at the last step, and it's doing 5-fold CV per feature tested, it'll generate 3 * 5 models at the final step.

Comment: I want the model with the best accuracy of the final step. I mean, if I could get all the models from the final step, I could determine the best one from that myself. As the SequentialFeatureSelector doesn't keep any of its models fitted during cv (taken from your edit), this seems not possible.

Comment: You could get the parameters of the model and fit it on the best features, as follows: `from sklearn.base import clone; best_model=clone(selector.estimator)(**selector.estimator.get_params()).fit(selector.transform(X), y)`. If you want *identical* models (down to the random seed) it'll also be necessary to set up the CV appropriately.